# How to create method which works only with predefined types in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I need to create such an overloaded operator, which works only with predefined types (e.g. works with *ofstream, stringstream*, but doesn't work with *ostream* & *iostream*)
. Here is an example:

```
// Possible usage: class Test : public BinaryTemplate  -  now you can simply write&read class Test from/to a file

class BinaryTemplate
{
public:
    template <typename K>
    // friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, K const&); // LINKER ERROR 2019
    friend std::ios& operator << (std::ios&, K const&); // OK
}

template <typename Stream, typename K>
Stream& operator << (Stream& out, K const& c)
{
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&c), sizeof(K));
    out.flush();
    return out;
}

BinaryTemplate bt;
cout << bt; // LINKER ERROR 2019 or OK
```

The compiler's behavior is very strange ( I hope it's clear for understanding 
according to commented errors). When I declare friend method like `<ios>` it's OK, because `cout` object is instance of `ostream`, which is derived from `ios`. But when I declare friend method like `<ostream>` it causes LINKER ERROR, but `cout` object is instance of `ostream`, then it is very strange for LINKER ERROR to be caused.
So, my question is:

**Why Linker has such a behavior and how should I create class method, which works only with predefined types?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: What does "predefined types" mean?

Comment: The friend declaration is not the same as the actual function definition. They differ in the number of template arguments and most likely in the type of the first function argument.

Comment: @KirilKirov it means that I want my method to work only with `ostream` and `ostringstream` instances(objects)

Comment: Even if you got that to build, writing arbitrary binary data and reading it back is a bad idea.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, but it's no problems here. Compiler tries to instatiate my template method, it finds function definition (yes, it differs from the friend declaration) and if the template is suitable (in my example the template is suitable for both friend declarations) it instantiate the template. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you want only 2 types - why not just define 2 different functions, why the template?

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you a lot for response. Could you explain some details? (Maybe as an answer to my question)

Comment: @KirilKirov Actually I want 4 types. Anyway, even for 2 types, just copying code isn't a solution, is it?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean with "the compilers behavior is very strange"? Strange how? If you get build errors, please provide the actual, unedited and *complete* error log.

Comment: @JamesAkwuh Just consider any class that contains a pointer, either directly or indirectly (e.g. by way of a `std::vector`).

Comment: You can have 4 overloads that delegate to a private (undocumented, hidden, concealed) template function

Comment: The reason for the "strange" linker behaviour is that neither friend declaration matches your definition. However, the declaration with `ostream` matches `cout << bt` so it's considered a forward declaration of that function (which you never define).